# How was the USS Enterprise going to leave Nibiru without being seen?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-into-darkness

In *Into Darkness*, Spock said that being seen by indigenous species violates the Prime Directive, and therefore he didn't want to be saved.  Even if the crew of Enterprise listened to him, it wouldn't make any difference because they would eventually come out of the water.

**How were they going to rise from the ocean and travel into space without exposing themselves to the indigenous people?**

Comment: Maybe they were going to leave at night :-)

Comment: Possibly the same way they arrived? If you can buy into the fact they arrived unseen, why could no do the same while leaving?

Comment: They were probably going to do the old "Silent Service" routine and leave the area at night keeping submerged until they were out of eyesight. That's what Tom Clancy would have done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite simple if you think about it. The enterprise just had to leave during the night and wouldn't be seen at all when she came out of the water. The problem was mostly that they made the "emergency" start during the day to save the first officer of the enterprise (and the other shuttle occupants).

Comment: They wouldn't even need to wait for night if they were in a hurry, just move further out to sea, beyond the horizon.  (I don't know if the natives had seafaring boats, but presumably the ships sensors could easily locate them.  It shouldn't be a problem to find somewhere safe to emerge.)

Comment: yepp that is why I the night is only an example. there are dozens like fog,... but we know a bit too few details about the planet to detail everything out. furthermore they could have easily done even then so....if not for the emergency where they didnt have any time to spare

Answer (score 1):

Probably hoping the natives were looking the other way, and hadn't noticed the scroll had been stolen. The only reason Enterprise was seen was because Kirk and McCoy were chased to the cliff by the locals.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! While your post does provide answer, you do not have supporting evidence. Please take our tour to see the kind of answers we are looking for.

Comment: It's stated in the movie that the scroll was taken specifically to get the natives away from the impending eruption.  The only reason the Enterprise had to surface was because the shuttle crashed and they couldn't retrieve Spock.